# Epsilon-delta limit proof for quadratic expressions.

Tags: calculus

I do understand how it usually works by arbitarily assuming some factor is less than 1, so the choice for the delta is usually in form of min{1,epsilon/c}.

But when I didn't learn the method, I approached differently, and I just wanted to check if this is a valid proof as well.

[image]

Edit: i just found a mistake on 7th line from bottom. The left hand side of the conjunction inequality should say 2-sqrt(4+e), not -2-sqrt(4+e). But this doesn't affect the result, because later the left side is ignored anyway.

Comment: Please don't make us follow your links.  Post your question here.  And give us some idea of where exactly you are stuck, or what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I posted this on my phone, and on the mobile website, the picture just shows up in the post, not the link. I assumed it would look the same on desktop. My bad

Comment: I think that this is tougher to follow than the "arbitrary 1" proof.  And clarity is important.  While it is true in this case. I should point out that you must make sure that $\delta > 0$ for any $\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but your argument has a mistake after the line marked with 1 (circled);

it should say $\color{red}{2}-\sqrt{4+\epsilon}<x-2<-2+\sqrt{4+\epsilon}$.

You can use $|x+2|=|(x-2)+4|\le|x-2|+4<(\sqrt{4+\epsilon}-2)+4=2+\sqrt{4+\epsilon}$ instead.

Comment: Yes. I found the mistake earlier :) but other than that, do you think this proof is also valid? If so, to me, personally, this is more straightforward than the usual "arbitrary 1" proof, and I was wondering why I can't find this similar proof anywhere.

Comment: The step where you conclude that $|x+2|<\sqrt{4+\epsilon}+2$ also doesn't follow from the preceding step, as written.  I agree with you that your method of proof is simpler in some ways, especially if you use the graph of $y=x^2$ to show why this choice of $\delta$ works.